Percent symbol in qwraps2 summary table not rendering properly in bookdown
I am struggling to get a qwraps2 summary table to render properly in a markdown file knitting to a pdf document using bookdown. The issue arises when using the percent sign in the row names.
Sample markdown document:
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "TEST"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  bookdown::pdf_document2: null
---

```{r results = 'asis'}
library(qwraps2)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

# Create som sample data
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(
  group = as.factor(sample(c("A","B"),8, replace = T)),
  value = sample(2:10,8, replace=F),
  pos = as.factor(sample(c("pos.","neg."),8, replace = T))
)

# Define the table for summary_table
summary <- list(
  "Groups" = list(
    "Value" = ~ median_iqr(value),
    "Pos. (\\\\%)" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(pos == "pos."))
)

new_table <- summary_table(df, summaries = summary, by = "group")

new_table

I am aware that the percent sign needs to be escaped with backslash, but with two backslashes the rendering fails. With four the table is not rendered correctly. See below.

How do I add a percent sign to the qwraps2 summary table row?

I found a work-around using gsub replacing (%) with (\\%) after summary_tablehas parsed the table seems to work.

use option(qwraps2_markup = "markdown") when working in .Rmd files so the output of summary_table and qable is markdown.

This looks like a bug in R triggered by bad code in qwraps2.
The qwraps2 package converts the summaries argument to a character string and then parses it, purely for the purpose of giving a warning about using data in summaries.  This doesn't make sense:  summaries is already a list, so it shouldn't need parsing.  That code should be fixed.
However, the bug in R is that the conversion to a character string is done incorrectly when you have  "Pos. (\\%)" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(pos == "pos."), and that's why you get the error.
The easiest fix I can think of is to remove that warning from the qwraps2:::summary_table.data.frame function.  If you insert this code into your document, you'll do that:
summary_table.data.frame <- qwraps2:::summary_table.data.frame
body(summary_table.data.frame)[[2]] <- NULL

After that change, you can use
summary <- list(
  "Groups" = list(
    "Value" = ~ median_iqr(value),
    "Pos. (\\%)" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(pos == "pos."))
)

and things will be fine:

However, this fix is not very robust:  if the author of qwraps2 changes that function, this could fail badly.  So your workaround of
editing the result of the summary_table call is probably safer.

Thank you. This makes me consider ditching qwraps2 altogether.

The primary issue is that the default behavior of qwraps2 is to generate LaTeX output.  When working in Rmd it is perfferable to set options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown") (see my answer below).
That said, the need to improve the check for the use of the .data pronoun can be improved.  That is the cause of the error with \\% is used.  I've documented this on github and will work on it soon.

qwraps2 author here.  The issue is due to the formatting issues between LaTeX and markdown.  When I wrote the package originally I was working in Rnw files almost 100% of the time.  That means the default output for the summary_table and other calls to qable works well for .Rnw files.
When working in a .Rmd or .qmd file qwraps2 works a lot better if you set the markup language option to markdown.  You can do this explicitly in the function calls or set the option.
Since you are writing a .Rmd use option(qwraps2_markup = "markdown") and the formatting will be much easier.  See below:
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "TEST"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  bookdown::pdf_document2: null
---

```{r results = 'asis'}
library(qwraps2)
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

# Create som sample data
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(
  group = as.factor(sample(c("A","B"),8, replace = T)),
  value = sample(2:10,8, replace=F),
  pos = as.factor(sample(c("pos.","neg."),8, replace = T))
)

# Define the table for summary_table
summary <- list(
  "Groups" = list(
    "Value" = ~ median_iqr(value),
    "Pos. (%)" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(pos == "pos."))
)

new_table <- summary_table(df, summaries = summary, by = "group")

new_table
```

Results in the output:

